# What is the size of a image field content in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datalength

I have a table in SQL Server. This table has an image field and the application stores files in it.

Is there a way to read the size of the file in the image field using T-SQL?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(imagecol) FROM  table
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: The result will be the *number of bytes*.

Comment: In _megabytes_ it would be `SELECT DATALENGTH(imagecol) / 1048576.0 FROM  table`

Answer (score 15):

Different display styles:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(imagecol) as imgBytes,
       DATALENGTH(imagecol) / 1024 as imgKbRounded,
       DATALENGTH(imagecol) / 1024.0 as imgKb,      
       DATALENGTH(imagecol) / 1024 / 1024 as imgMbRounded,
       DATALENGTH(imagecol) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 as imgMb
FROM   table
```

Example output:

```
imgBytes    imgKbRounded    imgKb       imgMbRounded    imgMb
68514       66              66.908203   0               0.065340041992
```